# Form not submitted when progress bar reach 100%

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I attached, below, the simplified version of my php.
I have a from with multiple input field + upload file option.

When the form is submitted the upload bar fires up and when it reaches 100% I see the “success” alert and then the “complete” alert. (twice???)
However neither the form “action=sendEmail.php” is triggered not the “url: sendEmail.php” – I thought of adding both to see if any is triggered.
A note, when I remove the ajaxFrom triggers “sendEmail.php” is carried out.

So what am I doing wrong? What should  change to make the “sendEmail.php” carried out.
Also why do I see the success & completer alert twice?
***`Success => complete => success => complete`***

The basic form:

```
 <form id="formmail" class="form-horizontal" name="formmail" method="POST" action="sendEmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
.
```

I tried (separately of course) both  with a submit button:

```
<input class="btn btn-sm" name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' tabindex='100' value="Submit"/>
```

And a simple button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" name='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>
```

The javascript:

```
var progress
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var form_data = $("#formmail").serialize();
        $("#formmail").ajaxForm({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendEmail.php",
            data: form_data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#progressBar").removeClass("hidden");
                progress = "0%";
                $('.progress-bar').css("width", progress);
                $('.progress-bar').html(progress);
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                progress = percentComplete + "%";
                $('.progress-bar').css("width", progress);
                $('.progress-bar').html(progress);  
            },
            success: function (data){
                alert("success");
            },
            complete: function(xhr){
                if(xhr.responseText) {
                    alert("complete");
                }
            },
        })
        .submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can put `$("#formmail").submit()` after `alert` success

Comment: @PareshMaghodiya Did you try? It will submit the form one more time.

Comment: yes i tried - i get the alert messages and the upload but form is not submitted. "sendEmail.php" is still not carried out

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a very common problem. By default, Submit button (`<input type="submit">`) will submit the form automatically. Binding a `click()` function with jQuery won't stop the form from submitting. Therefore, for every click on submit button, `sendEmail.php` might be called twice, one by HTML form submit and one by JS. You probably want one of them only.

You can either change the type of the button to `type="button"`, or add `event.preventDefault()` in your `click()` function.

By the way, here are some recommendations for your codes:

1. for HTML tidiness, do not mix single quotes & double quotes in HTML structure. Also, remove unused `class` and `id` attributes.
2. use lowercase filenames only. uppercase in URL is not friendly for users.

Comment: thank you, that explains why i saw to alert messages twice.
But why cant i get the action php to be executed?
I tried placing withe action="upload.php"
and in teh ajax url: "upload.php"

none is carried out?

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in Developer Console. Is there any JS error?

Comment: no errors.
when i remove the ajaxform the "sendEmail.php" is carried out.